# Block text entry in a RichTexBox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox

I use a RichTextBox on my website. I just want to put inside it a description text for my home page. How block the text entry ?

This is my code :

```
<RichTextBox Name="RTBHome" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Height="49" >
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="Welcome to FluxCatcher , want to get your tweet, the informations about our favourite website"/>
        <LineBreak></LineBreak>
        <Run Text="and so much more in the same page ? So let's subscribe now"/>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.isreadonly%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Is it really easier to post here than to Google first or RTFM?

Answer (score 2):

RichTextBlock is what you're after:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextblock(v=vs.95).aspx

> Represents a control that displays read-only rich text.